# How to use OutputDebugString to add pointer

Tags: c++, visual-c++

I have code in debug mode:

```
OutputDebugString(_T("Element Name = ") + (Node->getParentElement() == NULL ? "null" : Node->getParentElement()->getName()) + _T("\n"));

 //getname() type is CString and GetParentElement() type is CXMLElement
```

With this code I'm getting below error:
error C2110: '+' : cannot add two pointers. 
I understand that two pointers can not be added.

What API should I use to clear this error?

Comment: Convert one of the pointers to a C++ string (either `std::string` or `CString`). Or better yet, stop using pointers for strings in C++, and use available string classes to begin with.

Comment: You can also use `std::osstringstream` if you are favoring the standard library over MFC.

Answer (score 1):

You can use it as following :

```
TCHAR msgbuf[256]; //keep required size
sprintf(msgbuf, "The value is %s\n", charPtrVariable);
OutputDebugString(msgbuf);
```

Comment: This will work for non-Unicode projects. Use `wsprintf` and `TEXT("The value is %s\n")` macro.

Answer (score 1):

Since the question is tagged with `C++`, I would suggest to use stringstream:

```
#include <sstream>
//...
std::stringstream ss;
ss << "Element Name = " 
   << (Node->getParentElement() == NULL ? "null" : Node->getParentElement()->getName()) 
   << std::endl;
OutputDebugString(ss.str().c_str());
```

Answer (score 0):

Because you cannot add two pointers together to concatenate strings, you can use a temporary `CString` object and append to it:

```
CString tmp = _T("Element Name = ");
tmp += Node->getParentElement() == NULL ? "null" : Node->getParentElement()->getName();
tmp += _T("\n");
OutputDebugString(tmp);
```

Comment: While this code may answer the question, it would be better to include some _context_, explaining _how_ it works and _when_ to use it. Code-only answers are not useful in the long run.